# .htaccess REQUEST_URI only one character redirect

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, request-uri

I'm basics to htaccess. I have an issue with htacess SEO Friendly URL.

For Ex:
If the URL is like www.example.com/A then htaccess should redirect to browse-category.php?alphabet=$1

My Code, but not working:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} [a-zA-Z]{1}$
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9-/]+)$ browse-category.php?alphabet=$1
```

If URL is like this www.example.com/add-business then it should redirect to $1.php.

Please help me and thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code in your `DOCUMENT_ROOT/.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

# if a matching .php file exists then internally forward /file to /file.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1\.php -f [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.+?)/?$ /$1.php [L]

# otherwise forward to browse-category.php?alphabet=$1
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ browse-category.php?alphabet=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: Thanks. Can you explain the above code. What is %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d and %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f. What it performs

Comment: `%{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d` means if request is is not for a directory and `%{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f` means if request is is not for a file. Have you tested it yet?